# How to count the number of times a unique value appears in a list?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm working on a sheet with a list of names, some repeating. I used the UNIQUE function to make a list of these names without the duplicates, and now I want to use COUNTIF to check how many times each unique name appears in the original list. I can't work out how to make it check the name from column B against the list in column A.

[Here's my sample sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QlmWTVC4pqkxEV41zMVutQV3GatB5EsqK3kxr_PjZO0/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to use =COUNTIF(A2:A,"(=INDIRECT(B2))") but it's returning 0 regardless of the actual count. I think my cell reference is wrong? I'm not sure how to get it to properly check against the text in B2, B3, etc.

bonus question: how do I make this formula apply as many times as it needs to automatically, e.g. if I paste a list of 100 names in column A and it returns 30 unique values in B, the formula needs to automatically populate in C2:C31 (ideally without having to click and drag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try this to auto-populate both the columns:*

```js
=let(Σ,unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),
     index({Σ,countif(A:A,Σ)}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using QUERY.

```cpp
=QUERY(A2:A,"select A, count(A)
             where A<>'' 
             group by A 
             label A 'Unique People', count(A) 'Count'")
```